# SwiftUI Line Graphs in iOS 15

Tags: swift, swiftui, graph, line, linegraph

How can I make a graph like this with SwiftUI in iOS 15, I know the Charts library is a great way but those are only available in iOS 16+. Is there a native way to make a chart like this? (no third party libraries)

The dots + labels should adjust with a slider value.

Comment: SwiftUI does not have a native solution for that and I don't know why you don't want to use 3rd party libraries, SwiftChart is great for that.

And developers in SO is not ChatGPT, we can't write a whole feature or library from scratch for a question

Comment: SwiftUI is very good in composing complex views from simple elements. So just start combining shapes like `Circle`, `Capuse`, `Path` and `Text` – and apply modifiers like `.rotate` or `.fill(.linearGadient ...)`

Comment: @ChrisR so I figured out drawing the lines, but the gradient is messing me up. Do you mind checking this out and seeing if there's anything I can do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74813626/swiftui-add-bottom-gradient-to-line-graph

Comment: @grandsirr no need to write a while feature from scratch, if you click the link above I've hammered quite a bit, just need some help with the gradient